# How to trigger an animation after adding the view to the view hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, animation, cashapelayer

I'm trying to animate a circle that is being drawn, I know how to do that, however, I do not seem to be able to find any information on how to trigger an animation after a button has been clicked or after data has been updated by a service.

The easiest solution for this would be to use CAShapeLayers. I need to update the time and then show that in the form of a few circles on top of each other.

I also have code to be able to do this in the drawRect method but I don't know yet which is the better solution for updating the circles. Do you guys know how to do this?

This is my code while using CAShapeLayers:

```
private var _greyCircleLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
private var _transpartentOrangeOneCircleLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
private var _transpartentOrangeTwoCircleLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
private var _transpartentOrangeThreeCircleLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
private var _transpartentOrangeFourCircleLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
private var _solidOrangeCircleLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

private var _currentDisplayedTime: Double = Double(0.0)

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configure()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    configure()
}

private func configure() {
    addCAShapeLayer(self._greyCircleLayer, colour: StyleGlobals.StrokeColor.CGColor)
    addCAShapeLayer(self._transpartentOrangeOneCircleLayer, colour: StyleGlobals.TransparentOrange.CGColor)
    addCAShapeLayer(self._transpartentOrangeTwoCircleLayer, colour: StyleGlobals.TransparentOrange.CGColor)
    addCAShapeLayer(self._transpartentOrangeThreeCircleLayer, colour: StyleGlobals.TransparentOrange.CGColor)
    addCAShapeLayer(self._transpartentOrangeFourCircleLayer, colour: StyleGlobals.TransparentOrange.CGColor)
    addCAShapeLayer(self._solidOrangeCircleLayer, colour: StyleGlobals.SolidOrange.CGColor)
}
```

And then I try to animate the layers with the following method, however it does not work. It only works when calling it after having added the layers to the view hierarchy:

```
func animateCircle(duration: NSTimeInterval, shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer, timeStart: CGFloat, timeEnd: CGFloat) {

    /*//let duration = 1.0
    let delay = 0.0 // delay will be 0.0 seconds (e.g. nothing)
    let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut // change the timing curve to `ease-in ease-out`

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: options, animations: {
        // any changes entered in this block will be animated
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = timeEnd
        }, completion: { finished in
            // any code entered here will be applied
            // once the animation has completed

    })*/

    // We want to animate the strokeEnd property of the circleLayer
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

    // Set the animation duration appropriately
    animation.duration = duration

    // Animate from 0 (no circle) to 1 (full circle)
    animation.fromValue = timeStart
    animation.toValue = timeEnd

    // Do a linear animation (i.e. the speed of the animation stays the same)
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

    // Set the circleLayer's strokeEnd property to 1.0 now so that it's the
    // right value when the animation ends.
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = timeEnd

    // Do the actual animation
    shapeLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "strokeEnd")
}
```

Comment: Use CAAnimation to scale the CAShapeLayer

Comment: I've added code to demonstrate that I know how to animate the layers, its just that the animation does nothing when calling the animateCircle method somewhere else rather than just having added the layers to the view hierarchy in the init function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found my answer in the following tutorial:

http://blog.pixelingene.com/2012/02/animating-pie-slices-using-a-custom-calayer/

Looking at the PieSliceLayer class, it shows how with observable fields you can animate the changes.

Also when adding the layer to the UIView class, you need to call setNeedsDisplay() on it to be able to show it. It does not show by default.

Below is my code:

```
class HourLayer: CAShapeLayer {

@NSManaged private var _startAngle: CGFloat

@NSManaged private var _endAngle: CGFloat

@NSManaged private var _fillColor: UIColor

@NSManaged private var _strokeWidth: CGFloat

@NSManaged private var _strokeColor: UIColor

@NSManaged private var _duration: CFTimeInterval

private var _previousEndAngle: CGFloat = 0.0
private var _previousStartAngle: CGFloat = 0.0

private var _nextLayerToAnimate: HourLayer?
private var _nextLayerToAnimateStartAngle: CGFloat?
private var _nextLayerToAnimateEndAngle: CGFloat?
private var _nextLayerToAnimateDuration: CFTimeInterval?

private let _lenghtOfArc: CGFloat = CGFloat(2 * M_PI)

internal var StartAngle: CGFloat {
    get {
        return _startAngle
    }
    set {
        _startAngle = newValue
    }
}

internal var EndAngle: CGFloat {
    get {
        return _endAngle
    }
    set {
        _endAngle = newValue
    }
}

internal var FillColor: UIColor {
    get {
        return _fillColor
    }
    set {
        _fillColor = newValue
    }
}

internal var StrokeWidth: CGFloat {
    get {
        return _strokeWidth
    }
    set {
        _strokeWidth = newValue
    }
}

internal var StrokeColor: UIColor {
    get {
        return _strokeColor
    }
    set {
        _strokeColor = newValue
    }
}

internal var DurationOfAnimation: CFTimeInterval {
    get {
        return _duration
    }
    set {
        _duration = newValue
    }
}

required override init!() {
    super.init()

    self._startAngle = 0.0
    self._endAngle = 0.0
    self._fillColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self._strokeWidth = 4.0
    self._strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self._duration = 1.0
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    fatalError("required init(:coder) is missing")
}

override init!(layer: AnyObject!) {
    super.init(layer: layer)

    if layer.isKindOfClass(HourLayer) {
        var other: HourLayer = layer as HourLayer
        self._startAngle = other._startAngle
        self._endAngle = other._endAngle
        self._fillColor = other._fillColor
        self._strokeWidth = other._strokeWidth
        self._strokeColor = other._strokeColor
        self._duration = other._duration
    }
}

override var frame: CGRect {
    didSet {
        self.setNeedsLayout()
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

override func actionForKey(event: String!) -> CAAction! {
    if event == "_startAngle" || event == "_endAngle" {
        return makeAnimationForKey(event)
    }
    return super.actionForKey(event)
}

/*internal func prepareLayerForAnimationAfterThisLayer(layer: HourLayer, startAngle: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat, duration: CFTimeInterval) {
self._nextLayerToAnimate = layer
self._nextLayerToAnimateStartAngle = startAngle
self._nextLayerToAnimateEndAngle = endAngle
self._nextLayerToAnimateDuration = duration
}*/

private func makeAnimationForKey(event: String) -> CABasicAnimation {
    // We want to animate the strokeEnd property of the circleLayer
    let animation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: event)
    // Set the animation duration appropriately
    animation.duration = self._duration

    // When no animation has been triggered and the presentation layer does not exist yet.
    if self.presentationLayer() == nil {
        if event == "_startAngle" {
            animation.fromValue = self._previousStartAngle
            self._previousStartAngle = self._startAngle
        } else if event == "_endAngle" {
            animation.fromValue = self._previousEndAngle
            self._previousEndAngle = self._endAngle
        }
    } else {
        animation.fromValue = self.presentationLayer()!.valueForKey(event)
    }
    animation.delegate = self
    // Do a linear animation (i.e. the speed of the animation stays the same)
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    return animation
}

override class func needsDisplayForKey(key: String) -> Bool {
    if key == "_startAngle" || key == "_endAngle" {
        return true
    }
    return super.needsDisplayForKey(key)
}

override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext!) {
    var center: CGPoint = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2)
    var radius: CGFloat = CGFloat((CGFloat(self.bounds.width) - CGFloat(_strokeWidth)) / 2)

    // Set the stroke color
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, _strokeColor.CGColor)

    // Set the line width
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, _strokeWidth)

    // Set the fill color (if you are filling the circle)
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.clearColor().CGColor)

    // Draw the arc around the circle
    CGContextAddArc(ctx, center.x, center.y, radius, _startAngle, _lenghtOfArc * _endAngle, 0)

    // Draw the arc
    CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathStroke) // or kCGPathFillStroke to fill and stroke the circle

    super.drawInContext(ctx)
}

override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation!, finished flag: Bool) {
    // Trigger animation for other layer by setting their values for _startAngle and _endAngle.

    /*if flag && _nextLayerToAnimate != nil && _nextLayerToAnimateStartAngle != nil && _nextLayerToAnimateEndAngle != nil && _nextLayerToAnimateDuration != nil {
    self._nextLayerToAnimate!._startAngle = _nextLayerToAnimateStartAngle!
    self._nextLayerToAnimate!._endAngle = _nextLayerToAnimateEndAngle!
    self._nextLayerToAnimate!._duration = _nextLayerToAnimateDuration!
    }*/
}
```

I have however the problem of not knowing which layer is animating and which layer should succeed it. Now trying to figure this out in the following question:

[Swift: Animate layers in sequence from UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028197/swift-animate-layers-in-sequence-from-uiview)

Answer (score 0):

normally a `UIView` will be added in the moment you add it with:

```
self.addSubView(viewToAdd);
```

If you have inserted your code for the animation inside your `UIView` (doesn't matter what kind of `UIControl` element it is ) you could trigger the drawing inside `drawRect()` with this:

```
viewToAdd.setNeedsDisplay();
```

`setNeedsDisplay` triggers the view to update itself and call the `drawRect` method which never should be called directly.

You could also let the view draw itself when it is ready. You can add the method `didMoveToSuperView()` inside your `UIView` and then call the `setNeedsDisplay()`.

Comment: So if I were to update the time inside my UI control, I could only refresh it by calling the method setNeedsDisplay(), when having the code in the right methods?

Comment: What time are you talking about? I think it would be better you would post the code you used to include the view which should be animated inside the parentview.

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah the circle's I draw represent time, so when I update the time I need to refresh or redraw the view. And the view is the class you are seeing above. It's an UIView that I subclass. In this UIView I have multiple layers that represent hours and minutes. And the subclass of the UIView is getting added to an UITableViewCell via the addSubView method.

Comment: But why do you have to set the time outside your view? Is it for animation or whats exactly the reason you need it?

Comment: Well I want to show the user the time they have to wait for something. This time has to update every minute. This has to be done in a tableviewcell. So even when the user is just viewing the cell and not scrolling the tableview, the cell has to refresh multiple circular views with the times that I get from a remote server.

Comment: Looks to me like you didn't describe the problem in your post with everything you really need, you just posted about the animation initially. Maybe you think again about whats your problem and update the post, otherwise nobody can help you. But why don't you setup a method where you can pass through a time as NSInteger or CGFloat which will be updated inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but then you would need to request the new values every second from your server and refresh your table everytime you received the new values. Its just a problem to  synchronieze them correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72399/discussion-between--and-orion).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
class MyView: UIView {

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        println("Animate Me!")
    }

}
```